# error: incompatible types: ImageObserver cannot be converted to java.awt.image.ImageObserver

Tags: java, graphics

Trying to display an image in java, but the error listed above keeps popping up. How can I fix it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ImageObserver{

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        Image image = new ImageIcon("Hyperspace.JPEG").getImage();
        g.drawImage(image, 3, 4, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because you call a class ImageObserver does not make it a `java.awt.ImageObserver`. You forgot to have your class extend `JPanel`. You also forgot to give your `paintComponent` method an `@Override` annotation, because you're currently not overriding anything.

Comment: Other issues: never read in an image from within a painting method. Read the image in once and then store it in a variable. Also, call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within your override, first line.

Comment: Also Google the Swing painting tutorials and read them all.